# How to check for duplicates among separate excel files

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have multiple (~20) Excel files and I want to check if there is duplicate data (e.g. name). Is there a way I can do this without going through every name of each file? Thanks!

Comment: The only way I can think about going about it would involve a VBA script (which I haven't worked out yet). Are you familiar/comfortable with VBA or macros? You could use a whole bunch of formulas as per [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16555816/i-want-to-compare-two-lists-in-different-worksheets-in-excel-to-locate-any-dupli), but that would get pretty unwieldy with 20 different workbooks.

Comment: It might help to know what version of Excel you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this. You can start a Query from a File Folder - it will import all the files in a Windows Folder and can append all their data together (assuming the file columns are consistent). It takes a few steps and a bit of fiddling in the M Scripting language, but the building blocks and further data manipulation is point-and-click

Here's a blog post that details the steps to combine Excel files:

http://dutchdatadude.com/combining-excel-files-using-power-query-for-excel/

To find the duplicates, I would duplicate the Query and use the Group By command in Power Query.  I would Group By Name and calculate Count.  Any row with Count > 1 is a duplicate.  Then you can return to the first Query (with all the detail rows) and Merge the 2nd Query that finds duplicates, joining on Name.